# How to handle regular expression?

Tags: c++, c, regex, scanf

I have a list of data that needs to be parsed.
The data looks like:

> Element1 \t OptionalElement2 \t OptionalElement3 \r\n

The Elements (values) are separated by '\t' and OptionalElement2 and/or OptionalElement3 may or may not appear. This means, I could have:

> Element1 \t \t OptionalElement3 \r\n

or

> Element1 \t OptionalElement2 \r\n

or

> Element1 \r\n

I wanted to read the values with regular expression in the C or C++ language using sscanf, with

```
while (counter < 3) {
    memset(buffer[counter], '\0', sizeof(buffer[counter])); 
    counter++;
}
sscanf(toParse, "%[^\t]%[^\t\r\n]%[^\t\r\n]\r\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2])
```

But then when OptionalElement2 is empty, buffer[1] gets the values of OptionalElement3 instead of an array of '\0'.
Is there a way to properly handle this, so that when the values are non-exitent, their appropriate containers are also empty?

Thank you.

Comment: If you simply want to parse a string with tab separated content, you might want to look at `strtok`. And you should decide which language you want to use. For C++ there might be different solutions.

Comment: `sscanf` doesn't use regular expressions. If you use `sscanf` at all, you must always check its return value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I however do not just want to parse the values, as each value need to be worked on. I will try strtok to see how it handles.

Comment: melpomene, since there are 2 cases with the exact same return value, i do not think that getting the number of element found would help.

Comment: melpomene, "sscanf doesn't use regular expressions" ? But i am using this function with regular expressions.

Comment: Would the downvoters please tell the OP what is wrong. Otherwise the question cannot be improved.

Comment: melpomene, I see what you mean. I will try to use regex from C++ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main question is, are you using C or C++ ? The outcome and the appropriate/expected answer will be given with the right information.

As you are talking about C++ also, I will put a sample code to manage this using the  library provided in C++ (since C++11 onwards).
Be warned than as I am in C++, I am not using sscanf(...) so it may or may not answer your request if you expect to use sscanf for your solution.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::string val{"Element1 \t OptionalElement2 \t OptionalElement3"};
    //std::string val{"Element1 \t OptionalElement2"};
    //std::string val{"Element1"};

    // the match object
    std::smatch m;
    // declare regular expression for matching (note that optional elements are marked as optional with the ? after
    // closing parenthesis
    std::regex myreg("^\\s*([\\w\\d]+)\\s*([\\w\\d]+)?\\s*([\\w\\d]+)?\\s*$");

    // check if there the match between our pattern and the content
    if( std::regex_match(val, m, myreg) )
    {
        // here there will be 4 values available
        // m[0]: the full line
        // m[1]: element 1
        // m[2] : Optional element 2 or an empty string if not found
        // m[3] : Optional element 3 or an empty string if not found
        std::clog << "Size of results:" << m.size() << "\n";

        // display one element
        std::cout << "Element 1: " << m[1] << "\n";
        if( m[2].matched)
            std::cout << "Element 2: " << m[2] << "\n";

        if( m[3].matched)
            std::cout << "Element 3: " << m[3] << "\n";

        // if you want to display all matched elements, here is the code
        /*for (const auto& entry: m)
        {
            if( entry.matched)
                std::clog << "Found: " << entry.str() << "\n";
        }*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Again, given information at my disposal, it may not answer your request but at least you have a working C++ version now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using C++11 and will use regex instead. Is there any performance decrease using regex instead of sscanf?